# Using async methods in initState() flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am using firebase and need to get the id of the user inside my initState() method as I am building a widget that requires the id of the user, from firebase. The `currentUser` method that firebase uses is a `Future`.

Currently, I have this as my init state and `getUser` function:

```dart
Future<FirebaseUser> getUser() async {
    FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    return user;
  }

void initState() {
    getUser().then((result) {
      stream = Firestore.instance.collection('Lessons').where("teacher", isEqualTo: result.uid).limit(4).snapshots();

      _AppBarOptions = <Widget>[
        AppBar(
          title: new Text('Dashboard', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        AppBar(
            title: new Text('Lessons', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
        AppBar(title: new Text('Tasks', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
        AppBar(
            title: new Text('Settings', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)))
      ];

      _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Dashboard will go here',
          style: optionStyle,
        ),
        StreamBuilder(
            stream: stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if(snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemExtent: 80.0,
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                      _buildListItem(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
                );
              } else {
                return Text('You have no Lessons');
              }

            }),
        Text(
          'Tasks will go here',
          style: optionStyle,
        ),
        Container(
          child: new RaisedButton(
            child: new Text('Sign Out'),
            onPressed: signOut,
          ),
        )
      ];
    });
  }
```

The problem that I am facing is that the `build` method is executed before this finishes, which uses the widgetOptions to display the text, resulting in an error.

I was wondering if there was any way to improve this as to be able to get the id of the user and use it in `stream` so that it can fetch the documents?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 5):

For such cases Flutter has [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget.

It "postpones" building of a UI piece to the moment when the provided `Future` completes.

Read the API docs of this class, view some examples and you will resolve your problem.

As a result you will unload the part of your `initState` method where you construct the list of options to the `builder` argument of the `FutureBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

To mitigate this problem, you can use a boolean and `setState()` to change its value. Once you have the id of the user, then you can build the widget that needs the user id if the boolean is `true`, and otherwise make the widget a progress indicator or simply "loading" text.